# Merging two lists with fields in python

Tags: python, list, merge, initialization

I'm trying to merge two lists of names so that the output is printed as "lastname, firstname".  I know how it should work logically, but need help with the initialization.

```
class Formatter:
    def __init__(self):
        self.firstNames = fn[]
        self.lastNames = ln[]

    def formatNames(self):
        nameList = self.__dict__.values()
        index = 0
        for item in nameList:
            print(self.LastName[index] + ", " + self.firstName[index])
            index += 1

fn = ["Mike", "Bob", "Billy"]
ln = ["Rose", "Smith", "Jones"]

Formatter()
```

Comment: Take a look at [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/functions.html#zip).

Comment: Can you be more specific about what the issue? Please see [ask], [help/on-topic].

Answer (score 0):

You can use the zip function here.

```
fn = ["Mike", "Bob", "Billy"]
ln = ["Rose", "Smith", "Jones"]

print(list(zip(fn, ln)))
```

The output would be.

```
[('Mike', 'Rose'), ('Bob', 'Smith'), ('Billy', 'Jones')]
```

Answer (score 0):

I re-factored your code and fixed your initialization. Here are two solutions to choose from.

```
class Formatter:
    def __init__(self, fn, ln):
        self.firstNames = fn
        self.lastNames = ln

    def formatNames(self):
        return list(zip(self.lastNames, self.firstNames))

fn = ["Mike", "Bob", "Billy"]
ln = ["Rose", "Smith", "Jones"]

f = Formatter(fn, ln)
formatted_names = f.formatNames()
print(formatted_names)
```

Output

```
[('Rose', 'Mike'), ('Smith', 'Bob'), ('Jones', 'Billy')]
```

---

```
  class Formatter:
    def __init__(self, fn, ln):
        self.firstNames = fn
        self.lastNames = ln

    def formatNames(self):
        return [f"{l}, {f}" for l, f in zip(self.lastNames, self.firstNames)]
  
fn = ["Mike", "Bob", "Billy"]
ln = ["Rose", "Smith", "Jones"]

f = Formatter(fn, ln)
formatted_names = f.formatNames()
print(formatted_names)
```

Output

```
['Rose, Mike', 'Smith, Bob', 'Jones, Billy']
```